# Convert list[adodbapi.apibase.SQLrow] to pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, adodbapi

Among sql-server connectors `adodbapi` is the only one that's working in my environment.

```
import adodbapi

conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Database={1}; \
       UID={2};PWD={3};".format(server,db,user,pwd))
cursor = conn.cursor()
query_list = [row for row in cursor]

type(query_list[0]) = adodbapi.apibase.SQLrow
```

How to convert this list into a pandas df?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
import adodbapi as ado
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_df(data):
    ar = np.array(data.ado_results) # turn ado results into a numpy array
    df = pd.DataFrame(ar).transpose() # create a dataframe from the array
    df.columns = data.columnNames.keys() # set column names
    return df

with ado.connect('yourconnectionstring') as con:
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        sql_str = 'yourquery'
        cur.execute(sql_str)
        data = cur.fetchall()
        df = get_df(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

import pandas as pd

```
.......
ur_statements
.......

query_list = [row for row in cursor]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':query_list })
print (df)
```

Comment: getting `KeyError: '_typ'`

Comment: Can i see your list

Comment: list looks like this: `<SQLrow={field1:Decimal('1234'), field2:'5678-9101112-12abc', field3:Decimal('1'), field4: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 8, 7, 45, 17), field5:1, row_id:Decimal('321895')}>`; will check the links, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider pandas' [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) to directly query the database. Currently, though you will recieve an error:

> KeyError: '_typ'

However, there is a working fix thanks to [@TomAubrunner](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27547#issuecomment-529893793) on this [Github ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27547) which appears to be a bug in `adodbapi`.

1. Find location of `adodpapi`: `print(adodbapi.__file__)`
2. Open the script in folder: `apibase.py`
3. Locate: `return self._getValue(self.rows.columnNames[name.lower()])` and replace with below `try/execpt` block:

   ```
   try:
       return self._getValue(self.rows.columnNames[name.lower()])
   except:
       return False
   ```

Once done, simply run as you would any DB-API pandas connection even with qmark parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import adodbapi

conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Database={1}; \
       UID={2};PWD={3};".format(server,db,user,pwd))

# WITHOUT PARAMS
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn)

# WITH PARAMS    
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [Col]= ?", conn, params=['myValue'])

conn.close()
```